# Error:-PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, pricebookentry

i am trying to solve this error but not able to solve, can anyone plz help me out. i have already set the standard pricebook.

**Error----**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row
>   0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception:
>   PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the
>   one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]
>       Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component  in page gen_multi_edit: Class.GEN_ProductSelectionController.save:
>   line 89, column 1
>
> Class.GEN_ProductSelectionController.save: line 89, column 1

controller-

```
public class GEN_ProductSelectionController {

    ID objCurrentOppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');    

     Public List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItemList{get;set;}
     public List<wrapOpportunityLineItem> wrapper{get;set;}
     public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList {get; set;} //Used for Search button
     public List<PricebookEntry> selectedProducts{get;set;}
     public String searchstring {get;set;}      

    //First page wrapper class
    public class wrapProduct {
            public PricebookEntry priceBookEntryList{get; set;}
            public Boolean selected {get; set;}

            public wrapProduct(PricebookEntry p) {
                priceBookEntryList= p;
                selected = false;
            }
    }


    //Display the products already available
    public GEN_ProductSelectionController(){
             wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();

             for(PricebookEntry a: [select Id, Name,ProductCode,UnitPrice,product2.Type__c from PricebookEntry]) {
             wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(a));
             }
             System.debug('Default product list :' +wrapProductList);
    }


     public void search(){  
             wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
             string searchquery='select name,id,Product2Id,ProductCode,UnitPrice,product2.Type__c from PricebookEntry where name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20';  

             for(PricebookEntry a: Database.query(searchquery)) {
                  wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(a)); //adding the searched products into list
                System.debug('Searched product list:' +wrapProductList);  
             }
     }  


   //Select button funtion
     public PageReference selectProduct() {
        selectedProducts = new List<PricebookEntry>();

            for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {

                 if(wrapProductObj.selected == true) {
                  selectedProducts.add(wrapProductObj.priceBookEntryList);
                 }
                 System.debug('Selected product list : ' +selectedProducts);
            }

            //system.debug('selectedWrapperList size ---------'+selectedProducts.size());
            PageReference pagePrice = new PageReference('/apex/GEN_Multi_Edit?id='+objCurrentOppId);
            opportunityLineItemList = [Select Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice,Monthly_Revenue__c,Contract_Start_Date__c,Full_Revenue_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,OpportunityId,User_Define_Products__c from OpportunityLineItem ];
            System.debug('Opportunity Line Item List :' +opportunityLineItemList);

            wrapper = new List<wrapOpportunityLineItem>();
            System.debug(selectedProducts);
            for(Integer i=0; i<selectedProducts.size(); i++) {
            // Pass new OLI with opportunity id

            wrapper.add(new wrapOpportunityLineItem(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = objCurrentOppId, User_Define_Products__c = objCurrentOppId, PricebookEntryId = selectedProducts[i].Id),
                                       selectedProducts[i]) );
            }


            pageprice.setRedirect(false);
            return pageprice; 

    }



    public PageReference Deletes() {
        return new PageReference('/'+objCurrentOppId);
    }

      public PageReference save() {
          List<OpportunityLineItem> lstOLI = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
          System.debug('Wrapper class:' +wrapper);
          for(wrapOpportunityLineItem obj :wrapper) {
              lstOLI.add(obj.oppLineItem);
          }
          insert lstOLI;
          return new PageReference('/'+objCurrentOppId);
     } 


//Clear button code on GEN_Product_Selection     
      public PageReference Reset() {
            return new PageReference('/apex/GEN_Product_Selection?id='+objCurrentOppId);
     }


    //Wrapper class for Gen_MultiEdit Page
    public class wrapOpportunityLineItem{

            public OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem{get;set;}
              public PricebookEntry selProd{get;set;}

            public wrapOpportunityLineItem(OpportunityLineItem oli, PricebookEntry sp)
            {  

               oppLineItem = oli;
               selProd = sp;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: You `opportuity.Pricebook2Id` should be equal with `OLI.Priceboo2Id`

Comment: Alright but where do I check that in this controller?

Comment: I suggest display only those pricebookEntry records where `pricebookEntry.PriceBook2Id  == opportunity.PriceBook2Id`

Comment: As through various links I found that I'll have to compare these but didn't understand where and why?

Comment: Okay I'll be trying that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like I said in comment your `Opportunity.Pricebook2Id` should be equal to  your `OLI.pricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id`

So for solution what you can do..

Query only those `PricebookEntry` where `pricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id = Opportunity.Pricebook2Id`

change your query in constructor and `search method`..

Note: Please be insure your opportunity pricebook2Id not null

```
public with sharing class pageclass {

public GEN_ProductSelectionController(){

    wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
    Id objPricebook2Id = [SELECT Pricebook2Id FROM Opportunity 
                           WHERE Id =: objCurrentOppId]; 
    for(PricebookEntry a: [select Id, Name,ProductCode,UnitPrice,product2.Type__c 
                            from PricebookEntry WHERE PriceBook2Id =: objPricebook2Id]) {
      wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(a));
    }
    System.debug('Default product list :' +wrapProductList);
}
```

Also in your search method change PricebookEntry query and add filter `PriceBook2Id =: objPricebook2Id`

Answer (score 1):

For CPQ users - The test methods or test data factory you wrote (or perhaps inherited like I did) likely use Test.getStandardPricebookId(); to set the Pricebook2Id field of PriceBookEntry records. However, CPQ automation (such as, when a Contract is saved with "Renewal Forecast" checked) may set the pricebook2 field of a record (such as, the renewal Opp) to be a different Pricebook. Solution in my case was to set the non-matching records to the Test.getStandardPricebookId() pricebook as well. I tried changing the pricebook of the pricebookentry records but the field is not writeable.